# Android location and Google Settings

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

so I have been developing this app for a few weeks now using my own handheld device and today I was trying to get Google map to center in on the current user location in my app

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //Locate the current position of the user
```

The setLocationEnabled(true) above should normally show the location of the user on the map and when the GPS button is pressed it will zoom into it.  However after I added the  following code this does not work anymore it doesn't show the location of the user anymore and I also I notice "Google Settings" was installed onto my device which after looking around was an update by Google so it might not be the code itself. But I do not know if Google Settings is the cause for this.

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
```

Even after commenting out this block of code the problem still persist. I do not know how to fix this and I hope someone could help me. I am not sure if this has to do with the code itself or just my device, it literally does not get the location of the user at all even though it was working for the past few weeks and it doesn't give any errors or warnings even pressing the GPS button on my map gives nothing no errors or warnings.

EDIT: I tried using an older working version of my code for this app and it still does not work in terms of getting the user location to come up on the map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use:

`map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(map.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),map.getMyLocation().getLongitude()), 15));`

The map store your actual location, so you dont need `LocationManager` class.

Comment: Hi I tried your code but I just got a runtime exception: cannot start activity.

Comment: you should check that you have the location: `if(mMap.getMyLocation() != null)`

Comment: until the map gets the location, it will take a little while.

Comment: I tried with the if statement and it still got a runtime exception. I'm not sure if this has to do with settings with the device. Normally the map.setMyLocationEnabled(true) function gets the user's current location but a while ago after I noticed this "Google Settings" app was installed it can't seem to retrieve the user's location using my app.

Comment: Also I think getMyLocation() is broken as it always return null.